# Fatal error when setting value for TableView Cell

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder

I'm getting this error when trying to pass values to text labels

```
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value:
```

After readying SO threads about this I've tried the following and no luck:

1. printed out each of the values from `photo` and the value was correct and not `nil`
2. deleted and reconnected the Outlets
3. created a dummy value of `username1Label.text = "test"` and same error

Here's a simplified version of the code:

```
class EventFeedCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var username1Label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var date1Label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var photoId1Label: UILabel!

func setPhoto(_ photo:Photo) {

    username1Label.text = photo.byUsername  //I get the fatal error here
    date1Label.text = photo.date
    photoId1Label.text = photo.postId
}}
```

And the `Photo` object

```
class Photo {

var postId = ""
var byId = ""
var byUsername = ""
var date = ""
var url = ""
var eventId = ""
```

}

**cellForRowAt**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    //Get a event feed photo cell
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: EventFeedCell.eventFeedPhotoTableCell, for: indexPath) as! EventFeedCell

    //Get the photo for this row
    let photo = photos[indexPath.row]

    //Set the details for the cell
    cell.setPhoto(photo)

    return cell

}
```

What else can I try?  This is an exact copy of another TableView cell that does work (and for that reason I added a `1` in the label names just to be sure they are unique)

Comment: There isn't enough detail but you may not be creating the cell correctly to have the `username1Label` outlet connected at runtime.

Comment: Start by pointing out the exact line causing the error. Also show us your `cellForRowAt` code where you create one of these `EventFeedCell` cells.

Comment: Just a word of advice to avoid future headaches, never use “!” always use the optional ? Then unwrap them and handle the cases where they are nil.

Comment: could the problem be that I have a tableview cell within a tableview within a tableview cell within a tableview?  It seems connected correctly

Comment: Temporarily change the first line in `setPhoto(:)` to use a string literal and see if it still errors.  if so, the problem will be with the connection between the cell & the code, if not it will be with the photo side of the equation

Comment: @flanker is setting the first line in ````setPhoto( : ) ```` as the same as the 3rd attempt above at fixing this?  ````username1Label.text = "test"```` .   How to debug issues between the cell & the code?

Comment: @akash23a to be clear, are you saying that you have a complete tableView nested within another tableView's dynamic tabeViewCell? If so, that's almost certainly behind the issue - I'd hate to imagine the chain of controllers, datasources and delegates, and all the optionals they entails.  And that's before cells containing tableViews start being reused!  I'd suggest rethinking the design!

Comment: @akash23a - sorry, yes, missed that.  So the problem is with the view hierarchy.

Comment: @flanker got it.  I'm over this, thanks!  Being new here do I delete a question that i started ifI abandon the approach?

Comment: @flanker the hierarchy is like this.  masterTableView > masterTableViewCell > tableView > EventFeedCell.  so the example below is tableView and EventFeedCell.  The masterTableView is static however the tableView is dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as the cell is initilized your labels and other UI components might be nil so you have to set a value only if your UI components (Labels etc ) are initialized otherwise don't set. Simply add `?` before you access the text properties. 
Here is a modified version of your `setPhoto(:)` method.

```
func setPhoto(_ photo:Photo) {

    username1Label?.text = photo.byUsername  
    date1Label?.text = photo.date
    photoId1Label?.text = photo.postId
}
```

One thing to note is if your photoModel properties are optional you have to unwrap them first before you try to access. Below is another vresion of your `setPhoto(:)` method only if your photoModel has optional properties.

```
func setPhoto(_ photo:Photo) {
      // Optionally unwrap your photo properties.
     gaurd let byUserName = photo.byUsername,
      let  date = photo.date,
      let postId = photo.postId else {return}

    // Safe to proceed if all your values are set in photoModel
    username1Label?.text = byUserName  
    date1Label?.text = date
    photoId1Label?.text = postId
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is sorta working based on adding the```` ?````.  Is there a way to wait until the UI Components is fully initialized before calling the ````setPhoto```` method?

Comment: Hi, @akash23a I think all you have to do is adding that ```?``` , It works all the time on most of my codebases, so I think that's all you need, but if you want to dig more, check the doc here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell and read articles about UITableViewCell life cycle methods. 
Don't forget to mark the answer if it solved your issue :)

Answer (score -1):

"Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value," suggests that you are trying to access a value that is nil. This often happens when you try to force-unwrap an optional that is not set.this error is likely occurring when you try to access photo.byUsername in your EventFeedCell's setPhoto method. The error indicates that photo.byUsername is unexpectedly nil. Before doing anything please check your **outlet Connections**.